# More accurate estimate of chess games possible

Tags: computer-chess, mathematics, game-complexity

I have heard of Shannon's number (10^120) which is the supposed number of possible chess games computed in the 1950s. But Shannon's estimate is criticised for including illegal moves.
What is a truer estimate under the given parameter

1. no illegal positions
2. FIDE rules of 3 fold rep and 50 moves are in force
3. we start from the regular starting position

Comment: Duplicate? https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8331/is-the-number-of-possible-chess-games-infinite?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peruse [this link](https://wismuth.com/chess/longest-game.html). Also see link for possible duplicate.

Sum-up of first link:

- Longest game under FIDE rules: 8848.5 (Fabel)
- Maximum mobility number: 218 moves
- Shannon's number, assuming 40 (full) moves, 30 moves per ply, ignoring FIDE rules and duplicates: 10^120
- Upper bound: 10^34082
- Realistic lower bound (Monte Carlo): 10^29241

Comment: Noted, with thanks. Your attached link is very helpful.

Comment: Also Shannon's number is an estimate of the number of positions possible after 40 ply or 40 moves?

Comment: I doubt that there are that many positions taking longer than either (although the retro genre knows many exceptions - but I bet they are rare).

Comment: The answer might be better if it at least summarized the link's estimate on the answer to the question. Links can disappear.

Comment: The gap between the upper bound and lower bound is HUGE.

Comment: @Zuriel: Not for a professional mathematician - the gap between Ramseys upper bound and the actual value (whatever exact problem my remark references to - I am no professional mathematician) - THAT is huge :-)